# Find a table across databases in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

I would like to find a specific table across multiple databases in Hadoop. I'm looking for an automatic solution since there dozens of databases involved.
Is there a hive command that could help me to do this?
Or I have to write something in bash instead?

Thanks

Comment: Query the metastore

Answer (score 0):

You can simply query your metastore. In my case i have mysql to be the metastore. so i did it this way

1. connect to your metastore. e.g mysql -uUser -hHost -pPassword
2. Use your metsatore db e.g use metastoredb;
3. select * from TBLS where TBL_NAME='table_name';

I have queried three columns and here is the output that i got.

select TBL_ID,DB_ID,TBL_NAME from TBLS where TBL_NAME='ri_reg_datamodels_tmp';

[image: screenshot of mymetastore]

ask me if you get any issue with it